# Why should we model Discrete & Continuous Random Variables differently?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I just started learning about The Normal Distribution in class and I was confused by the following paragraph in my textbook:

> Although at first sight it appears that the length of a leaf takes discrete values, this is only because the length has been measured to a given degree of accuracy. For example, when the length is given 63 mm, it means that the length, *l*, of the leaf lies in the range $62.5 \leq l < 63.5$. This suggests that a probability model for length, L, should give the probability that L lies in a certain interval rather than that L takes a particular value. Thus the approach to modelling continuous variables must be different than for discrete.

Why do we require a different approach? For example can't we assign ranges to a particular value and continue using methods for discrete random variables? So if a range is $30 \leq x < 40$,can't we assign it the value say $35$ and move on?

Comment: If $x$ is an integer then $30 \leq x < 40$ means $x \in \{30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39\}$ which has a crude average of $34.5$ not $35$.